# Invitation id can not be empty

Tags: android, google-play-services, parcelable

I have a strange bug report in my logs. Following is the stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invitation id can not be empty.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1550/1559/1544/1603)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499/1505/1493/1552)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzkn$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzkk.zzgh(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzkj$zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzkj$zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlx$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmd.begin(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmd.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmi.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmg.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmg.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzme.zzpi(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzme.begin(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmi.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlz.onConnected(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzg.zzk(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzqv(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zza.zzqv(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzc.zzqx(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzj$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135/211/145/148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294/5373/5835/5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904/1020/1399/726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699/815/1194/616)
```

I added with slashes variants of the stack traces where just the line numbers are different because of different android versions. I am using the play services, version 8.3.0. If you have any idea please leave an answer or a comment. Since that message [`Invitation id can not be empty`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Invitation+id+can+not+be+empty.%22) does not return any results when I searched on Google.

Please do not close it too fast since I want to link it on [Google+](https://plus.google.com/102418080865029037973/posts/KvTzFWTevZC) and on the [bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196993) to get feedback from Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked some more crash logs and found this one:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver my.package.name.ReferralReceiver: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invitation id can not be empty.
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2680)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invitation id can not be empty.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1559)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1505)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzkn$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzkk.zzgh(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzkj$zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzkj$zzd.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlx$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmd.begin(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmd.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmd.begin(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmi.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzmg.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzkj.convertInvitation(Unknown Source)
       at my.package.name.ReferralReceiver.onReceive(ReferralReceiver.java:72)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2673)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:156)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

That line of code which is causing the exception in this stack trace is this one:

```
AppInvite.AppInviteApi.convertInvitation(getApiClient(), invitationId);
```

So I would guess that this is related and the crash is caused by an empty `invitationId`. I added a null check, let's see if this crash will come back again.